# What should I do if wrong version of manuscript was uploaded and submitted to journal?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

I think I may have uploaded a version of the manuscript which was loaded with markups and typos. I can’t see what was submitted now. I sent an email to the editorial staff telling them I was concerned that I uploaded the wrong version. What is the likelihood they will let me send the correct version if it explicitly says on website “no changes after submission”? (The reason I think it was wrong version, the name they gave my manuscript file on submission included a  date that matched earlier version manuscript, (If that makes sense)coincidence?)

Comment: Was there a deadline? For instance, for a special issue submission?

Comment: No, just a normal article submission, nothing special about a deadline or anything.

Answer (score 1):

The odds are very good they'll let you do it. They have nothing to gain by sending a badly-formatted manuscript for review. You could even submit the correct version as a separate submission now and the most that'll happen is some minor inconvenience for the journal staff (this is when the [duplicate submission](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101864/can-you-share-some-screenshots-of-editors-control-panels/101865#101865) flag kicks in).

Worst case scenario, you can withdraw your submission and resubmit with the correct version.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am totally stressing about this.